# Getting undefined index when using ajax.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to echo data from php to jquery and the problem is that somehow jquery is not passing the data to php. The `var_dump` of the variable `$url` echo's `string''` or `NULL`.
Expected output is to echo what the user had typed on the input field on screen where the `id="domain-hits"` is.

HTML

```
<div id="domain-hits"></div>
<input onblur="checkPR()" type="text" class="input_text_metas_submit" name="url" value="http://" id="urlpr" />
```

Jquery / AJAX

```
$(function () {
    jq2('#urlpr').on('blur', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'onlydomain.php',
            data: $('#urlpr').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#domain-hits").html(data);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

PHP - onlydomain.php

```
<?php
  $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
  var_dump($url); // it echo's string ''.
?>
```

I am a noob in ajax please help me on this, it's much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending the form data via POST by trying to retrieve it via GET. Change:

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
```

to:

```
$url = isset($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : '';
```